# How do I defeat a Pyro being a Pyro?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-pyro

I would like some tips to beat the other pyro being a pyro.

What weapons should I use? 
Is it more favorable to use a shotgun rather than a flamethrower?

Comment: I have been experimenting with landing guaranteed critical flares on enemy Pyros, and taunting when they die as a result.

Comment: Also I'm not sure if this would exactly answer your question so I'm posting it here first: when you're running in with an ÜberCharge, the best way to deal with Pyros airblasting you back is of course to kill them ASAP, regardless of which class you're playing. If you're a Pyro, you can just aim enemy rockets at them to get rid of them first. A single sentry rocket should take one out at direct hit (190+ damage). That's what I always do, and it's pretty effective sometimes.

Comment: @TheAnnoyingPyro: I would like a response from you. You seem experienced. I'd love you to share a list of your knowledge with me (us) on the fighting involving two pyros:) Please, consider a simple fight, without ÜberCharge.

Comment: I'm great against Soldiers and Demos but terrible against other Pyros :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would say, at flamethrower range, PvP is mostly about who gets the drop on the other, and who has the better dodging/tracking/strafing skills.

However, if you have a shotgun and the other Pyro has a flare gun, you have a huge advantage at medium range, and you should seek to remain at that range.

Against an aggressive opponent, you can sometimes control your range between them. Jump back out of flamethrower range as he chases you with the flamethrower, then close in and switch weapons if he switches to shotgun while still moving forward. Additionally, you can force a medium range encouter with the airblast, allowing your (hopefully) greater dueling skills to win the day.

Since two good pyros will probably be doing this, it often devolves into a shotgun duel.

Comment: If I'm airblasting an enemy Pyro, I 1) **use all the ammo I can** to do it (which often takes us across the area) and/or 2) close in with my Powerjack. Unfortunately, in most cases I'm the one with the Flare Gun...

Comment: I guess if you don't play Pyro offensively, then there's almost no way you're getting an edge over those who do. I'll probably just run back to the sentry nests I so faithfully spend my time guarding and let my Engineers repay some of the love I give them :)

Answer (score 6):

[Degreaser](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Degreaser) + [Reserve shooter](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Reserve_Shooter). Afterburn damage penalty does not apply and you can get mini-crits on them with the reserve shooter when they're puffed up in the air. Degreaser also lets you switch weapons faster.

Comment: As a pyro, how do you use both?

Comment: @Pureferret: Airblast, switch, pump.

Comment: This is probably the best if you're 1 on 1 mulching, but in my inexperience, leaves you much worse-off in general.

Comment: @TheAnnoyingPyro Isn't the reserve shooter a soldier only gun though?

Comment: @Pureferret: [The Manniversary Update](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/October_13,_2011_Patch) allows Pyros to equip the Reserve Shooter.

Comment: @TheAnnoyingPyro Wow, I've not played in a long time :(

Comment: @NickT Degreaser + Reserve Shooter + Axetinguisher is a great general purpose pyro loadout if you're good at weapon switching (I have quick switch enabled and weapons bound to Q, E and F). It's all based around airblasting and hitting them in midair with the axetinguisher or reserve shooter.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some very basic advice for flamethrower/flamethrower combat (say you're equipped with a flaregun and so have no shotgun). It is quite possible to defeat another Pyro with the flamethrower without it coming to who has slightly more health, given sufficient skill.

- Never chase another Pyro with the flamethrower (unless to airblast them up against a wall or off a cliff); but if they chase you, just flame at them and run backwards. You have a range advantage (you're “upwind”) and so will do significantly more damage.
- If they're circling around you, lead your aim a bit more than you would for bullets. Practice with hit sounds turned on to learn the right angle. Make sure you can track them consistently so they have no opportunity to get close without taking damage.
- Use airblast just to mess up their aim and movement rather than changing the range — or to get out of range just when they think they've got you. If you can pop them up and against a wall, do it, then circle to another angle and keep flaming.

None of this helps if they're staying out of flamethrower range, of course.

Answer (score 1):

It comes down to the player with better movement, I tend to favour the shotgun when fighting Pyro on Pyro  due to Pyro taking less damage over time when using the flamethrower on them also no after burn.. Shotgun requires at base 3 good shots to take down a standard pyro (no unlocks etc). However if you know you aren't going to miss at all with your flamethrower then by all means use it due to the highest damage per second out of the two choices.

Hope this sort of helps just for the most part Tf2 is situational and you'll be able to tell what is the best choice over time from experience and past encounters.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get around to their back, the Backburner is especially powerful for taking out other pyros, since they are still vulnerable to the mini-crits that it dishes out.  Though you should be aware that if you're taking them head-on, your ability to airblast them is reduced, which is a major disadvantage.

Backscratcher is the best Pyro Melee Weapon for pure damage-dealing, but any flamethrower can beat it in pure DPS.  However, if you make an initial strike with the Backscratcher, and then switch to the flamethrower using one of the switch-fast weapons (Reserve Shooter/Degreaser), you may get a greater overall damage output on them.

Also keep in mind that pyros CAN be crit while 'on-fire' immediately after being hit with a flamethrower.  I haven't tested this so I cannot guarantee an Axetinguisher strike will work, but a flare strike might, though you'd have to time it incredibly well.